# Multiple different Collada scenes with Three.js animation won't work

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I have a multiple models in Collada format (knight.dae & archer.dae).
My problem is that i can't get them all to animate(lets say Idle with is 2-3frames).
When i load the scene i either get only one animated model and one stil model(no animation,no nothing,it's like he's being modeled in 3ds max).
I know my problem is with the skin and morphs but i searched alot and didnt find an answer and due to my lack of experience my attempts have failed so far.
Help pls!

```
//animation length of the model is 150(and it hosts 4 different animations)
var startFrame = 0, endFrame = 150, totalFrames = endFrame - startFrame, lastFrame;
var urls = [];
var characters = [];
urls.push('3D/archer/archer.dae');
urls.push('3D/archer/archer.dae');
//here's the loader
loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
        loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
        for (var i=0;i<urls.length;i++) {                           
        loader.load(urls[i],function colladaReady( collada ){
            player = collada.scene;
            player.scale.x = player.scale.y = player.scale.z =10;
            player.position.y=115;
            player.position.z=i*200;
            player.updateMatrix()
            skin = collada.skins [ 0 ];
            //skinArray.push(skin);;
        var mesh=new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(10,20,10,1,1,1));
        player.add(mesh);
        characters.push(mesh);
        scene.add( player );
            });
        }
//i added the cube because i use raycaster and it doesnt detect collada obj


// Here is where i try my animation.
        function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        render();

    }
        function render() {
        update();
        renderer.render(scene,camera);

    }
    function update() {
        var delta = clock.getDelta();
        delta = delta / 2;      
        if ( t > 1 ) t = 0;
        if ( skin )
            {
        skin.morphTargetInfluences[lastFrame] = 0;
        var currentFrame = startFrame + Math.floor(t*totalFrames);
        skin.morphTargetInfluences[currentFrame] = 1;
        t += delta;
        lastFrame = currentFrame;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.... at the beginning:

```
var skins = [];
```

At your collada callback, something you already seem to have thought about:

```
skins.push(collada.skins[0]);
```

At your renderer, instead of the current if (skin) clause:

```
t += delta;
lastFrame = currentFrame;
var currentFrame = startFrame + Math.floor(t*totalFrames);

for (var i = 0; i < skins.length; i++) {
  var skin = skins[i];
  if (skin) {
    skin.morphTargetInfluences[lastFrame] = 0;
    skin.morphTargetInfluences[currentFrame] = 1;
  }
}
```

Point being, you need to loop all the skins in the update() function. I didn't check the frame handling code very carefully as that was not the question.. If your skins have different amount of frames you need to take those into account in your code (maybe make the lastFrame, currentFrame etc variables to arrays matching the skins array).

Comment: thank you for your answer but unfortunetly it didnt work,if i used your code my models with morph weird(scale big and not animate proper).

Answer (score 0):

```
        if ( skinArray[0] && skinArray[1] )
        {
        skinArray[0].morphTargetInfluences[lastFrame] = 0;
        skinArray[1].morphTargetInfluences[lastFrame] = 0;
        var currentFrame = startFrame + Math.floor(t*totalFrames);
        skinArray[0].morphTargetInfluences[currentFrame] = 1;
        skinArray[1].morphTargetInfluences[currentFrame] = 1;
        t += delta;
        lastFrame = currentFrame;
        }
```

I came up with this code,it does the job but i just don't like it,mainly because it feels it's hardcoded.So if any of you guys can come up with a more elegant solution i'd be more then happy.